# git alias doesn't wait for clone to finish before cd into project?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use a repo as a starting point for different projects.

I did follow this gist here: https://gist.github.com/mdentinho/6258238

And starting from the gist i've created an alias that looks like this:

```
boilerplate-website = !git clone -o website-boilderplate https://user@bitbucket.org/user/website-boilderplate.git "$1" && cd "$1" && rm readme.md && touch readme.md && rm -rf .git && git init && git add -A && git commit -m 'First Commit'
```

But it looks like the CD part is not working, as i am still in the directory i run the command from and not inside the newly cloned directory.

Also, because of this, I get this error and the alias doesn't complete all the commands (it just clones and that's it).

```
Cloning into 'test2'...
remote: Counting objects: 19, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 19 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
rm: readme.md: No such file or directory
```

Why is not waiting for the clone to finish? I did user regularly

```
git clone {repo} {folder name} && cd {folder name}
```

and that works fine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `cd` should affect new spawned shell, but not shell you run command from.

Comment: Is there any way i can achieve what i'm trying to achive from the alias?

Comment: The only way is to return the current directory path back to the current shell and `cd` in the current shell. Something like `cd "$(git boilerplate)"` where `boilerplate` ends with a call to `pwd` to echo the current path.

Comment: @phd sorry i didn't really understand what you mean...can you show me an example please?

Comment: .gitconfig: `boilerplate-website = !git clone… && cd "$1" && pwd`. Usage: `cd "$(git boilerplate-website URL)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [PetSerAl noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029346/git-alias-doesnt-wait-for-clone-to-finish-before-cd-into-project#comment83028951_48029346), `cd` affects the shell that executes the `cd` command, and any sub-commands/sub-shells that that shell itself spawns; but it does not affect any "outer layer" shells, like the one in which you type `git boilerplate-website`.  (The `!` in the alias means: "run this through a sub-shell.")

What this means for you is that you cannot achieve what you want this way.  You need your shell—the one into which you type some command—to execute the `cd` command.

The way to do that is to use a *shell function* or *shell alias* (the latter is different from a *Git alias*).  The specifics for defining a shell function or shell alias vary slightly depending on which shell you use, but it's common in bash and bash-like shells to have:

```
func() {
   commands
}
```

to be the way to define a function (in `$HOME/.bashrc` for instance), and:

```
alias name='expansion with arguments'
```

to be the way to define an alias.  Hence you could write:

```
newwebsite() {
    case $# in
    1) ;;
    *) echo "usage: newwebsite <name>" 1>&2; return 1;;
    esac
    git clone -o website-boilderplate \
        https://user@bitbucket.org/user/website-boilderplate.git \
        "$1" || { echo "git clone step failed, aborting" 1>&2; return 1; }
    cd "$1" &&
    rm readme.md &&
    touch readme.md &&
    rm -rf .git &&
    git init &&
    git add -A &&
    git commit -m 'First Commit'
}
```

(I've written this as a function to try to make it as readable as possible, while keeping your structure intact.)  Note that you would run this without the `git` command in front of it, i.e., `newwebsite foo` and not `git newwebsite foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would I then run the alias command? would it just be like the echo says "newwebsite <name>?

Comment: @Nick: yes, I must have done the edit to put that in while you were asking :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll give it a try :)

Comment: acqually, quick question: how would i add a second (optional) parameter= and how would i then check if it is there, and if it is run two more git commands? :)

Comment: That's getting into doing shell script programming (so you might want to read up on that), but: `case $# in` tests the number of arguments, so you can add a case for 2. You can also test whether an argument is empty with `if [ "$2" == "" ]; then ...` and if there is no `$2`, `"$2"` will expand to an empty string (but note that this is no longer distinguishable from when there *is* a second argument that is an empty string, which is something you *can* tell using `$#`).